# Phonegap globalization redirect language without button

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, globalization

This is the Javascript code for phonegap which redirects to the right html file.

```
 function checkLanguage() {
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
   function (language)
   {
       if(language.value == "English")
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeE.html");
       }
       else if(language.value == "Deutsch")
       {
           window.location.replace("fade.html");
       }
        else if(language.value == "Nederlands")
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeN.html");
       }
       else 
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeE.html");
       }
   },
   function ()
   {
       alert('Error getting language\n');
   }
 );
 }
```

It works perfectly with the button:

```
<body>
<button onclick="checkLanguage()">Click for language</button>
</body>
```

I want the function to be called without clicking on the button.

I tried body onload="" and to call the function in js like  checkLanguage() aswell. But is isn´t working.. 
Where is the mistake or how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the phonegap device ready function. But onClick="" with a capital C works also ;)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
   navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
   function (language)
   {
       if(language.value == "English")
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeE.html");
       }
       else if(language.value == "Deutsch")
       {
           window.location.replace("fade.html");
       }
        else if(language.value == "Nederlands")
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeN.html");
       }
       else 
       {
           window.location.replace("fadeE.html");
       }
   },
   function ()
   {
       alert('Error getting language\n');
   }
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") { checkLanguage(); }
```